# ngFor async keep rebuilding if values are reassigned

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-template

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dunfqr)

I have the following code,

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of myObjs$ | async">
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>{{obj.name}}</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
  </mat-menu>
</div>
```

My ngFor is assigned to an observable (that in real like is a selector from NGRX)>

I do this because I when a new element is loaded, I want the menu to autoUpdate, and also, some info in the menu is based on the object state and I also want it to update.

The problem is, the ngFor is constantly rebuilding the DOM, and when I open the matmenu, if it rebuild it will be removed and closed.

is there a way to fix this ?

**EDIT** : I tried *ngFor="let obj of MyObjs$ | async; trackBy:obj?.id " but still not working.

Comment: I think there is no need to use `async` pipe here bcs you value changes in every second. 
solution: you can subscribe that observer get the value if length of array is different from the previous one apply your changes.

Comment: but how about the value ```name``` that is updated, I need to update it in the menu. Now this is a simple exemple, in the app the object can have multiple changes only the ID is fixed.

Comment: You've set `Obervable` to constantly send 3 values every second and that's the reason why it's flashing. Can you add some details of what you trying to achieve? It depends on value that's selector points to but I believe you can distinguish if value changed or not.

Comment: here is a simulation to show the problem. IN the app the observable come from NGRX, and when there is more item loaded, or item changes that observable trigger with all the changes. but NGRX always reassign every objects in the reducer. so that is why I simulated like this.

Comment: @YashRami you would basically reimplement what angular does behind the scenes, so no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea was right, but you are defining the `trackBy` function in a wrong manner. Refactor as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of items$ | async; trackBy: trackItem">
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>{{obj.name}}</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
  </mat-menu>
</div>

import {Component, TrackByFunction} from '@angular/core';

interface Item {
  id:number;
  name:string;
}

@Component({...})
export class FooComponent {
  items$: Observable<Item[]>;
  trackItem: TrackByFunction<Item> = (i, item)=>item.id;
}
```

A working example can be found [in this blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/async-mat-menu)